# Class in array convert to JSON

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, class

I am doing TodoList, and 
want to save the list to a JSON file, but it saves only the Class name.

Here's the code:

```
require 'date'
require 'json'
class TodoList
    attr_accessor :title

    def initialize(title)
        @title=title
        @items=[]
    end

    def rename(title)
        @title=title
    end

    def add_item(new_item, due_date)
        item=Item.new(new_item)
        item.set_due_date(due_date)                
        @items.push(item)
    end

    def save
        if json_instance = self.to_json
            puts "Saved Successfully"
        end

        File.open("file_json_complete.json", "w") do |f|
            f.write(json_instance)
        end
    end
end

class Item
    attr_reader :complete_status, :description, :due_date, :created_at    

    def initialize(description)
        @description=description
        @complete_status=false
        @created_at=Date.today
    end
end

doh=TodoList.new("doh's stuff")
# Add four new items
doh.add_item("laundry", 10)
doh.add_item("study",20)
doh.add_item("sleep", 15)
doh.add_item("Watch Movie", 5)
doh.save
```

The result in the file only shows the class name `TodoList:0x00000000965e88`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this appropriately I would recommend adding the following:

```
class TodoList
   def to_json(options={})
     {title: @title, items: @items}.to_json(options)
   end
end

class Item
   def to_json(options={})
     {description: @description, completed: @complete_status,
      created: @created_at, due: @due_date}.to_json(options)
   end
end
```

Then when you call `to_json` on the `TodoList` you will get something similar to:

```
"{\"title\":\"doh's stuff\",
    \"items\":[
       {\"description\":\"laundry\",\"complete\":false,\"created\":\"2016-03-08\",\"due\":\"2017-01-08\"},
       {\"description\":\"study\",\"complete\":false,\"created\":\"2016-03-08\",\"due\":\"2017-11-08\"},
       {\"description\":\"sleep\",\"complete\":false,\"created\":\"2016-03-08\",\"due\":\"2017-06-08\"},
       {\"description\":\"Watch Movie\",\"complete\":false,\"created\":\"2016-03-08\",\"due\":\"2016-08-08\"}
    ]
}"
```

Which I am assuming is what you are looking for.

Basically `to_json` will recursively call `to_json` on the nested objects to create the structure this will end up defaulting to the `to_s` method when you have not implemented a `to_json` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the current instance of the `TodoList` class.
You have to save your `@items` variable. To do this you have to change `self.to_json` to `@items.to_json`

Answer (score 0):

```
class TodoList

  ...

  def save
    File.open("file_json_complete.json", "w") do |f|
      f.write(@items.to_json)
    end
    puts "Saved Successfully"
  end

  ...

end
```